# How to resolve 'Value cannot be null' error when using Azure Functions Core Tools?

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I am using Azure Functions Core Tools from a cloned repository. When I try to run `npm run watch` this error occurs: 
`Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')`
[Error in Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3ulm.png)

I've installed Azure Functions Core Tools from this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v3%2Clinux%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash%2Ckeda and was logged in on azure using azure-cli. I'm currently using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Did you see this github issue? https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2232 Also it might be advisable that you install the core tools explicitly  to resolve this issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#explicitly-install-extensions

Comment: @misha130 Thank you. It has some conflicts with extensionBundle included in host.json file of the application. Still wondering why it won't work on my end while some of my team setups were not having the conflict issues. I just did installed it explicitly like you said and it did work. The only problem is that there will be different project structure now since installing explicitly provide the bin folder and extensions.csproj and extensionBundle code should be removed. I will still investigate further why the original setup does not work on my end. other than that, thank you very much.

Comment: I'll add an answer in case other people encounter this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are situations in which it is best to install the Azure Function Core Tools explicitly to avoid any conflict or versioning problems:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#explicitly-install-extensions

Further discussion of this issue can be seen in:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2232

Comment: Thanks, @misha130 - It worked for me as it was a version issue.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error message. My access was blocked via the azure firewall (vnet, subnets) and therefore, the local debugging was blocked (my IP was not added to the related storage accounts). After I added my IP to allowed list everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue - the solution was to uninstall Azure Function Core Tools (Via "Add Or Remove Programs"), and then install them again

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Cts%2Cportal%2Cbash#v2

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34119103)

Comment: Actually, this also solved the issue for me too. Thanks!

Comment: Reinstalling solved my issue too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also had the same problem, and it seems like in my case the reason was low and unstable internet connectivity, I was trying to work from a hotel with bad internet connection.
The reason I think so is that when I came back home and tried to reproduce the error, everything started working without any code updates.